# How can I have multiple entry points in a package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I want to be able to run different commands with npm:

```
"scripts": {
  "v1": "node v1.js",
  "v2": "node v2.js"
}
```

with something like `npm start v1` or `npm start v2`, but these commands do not run the correct Node command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `npm run`:

```
npm run v1
```

or

```
npm run v2
```

To add extra parameters add `--`:

```
npm run v1 -- -param_one 1 --param2 2
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
node v1.js -param_one 1 --param2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

> The alternative would be to have a wrapper index.js or similar which
>   runs the correct version based off the argument supplied to npm start

You can access an array of arguments using `process.argv`, and those values should be available whether you use `npm start` or `node ./index.js`